# Time to list all schemas of PostgreSQL with QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, postgresql, performance, schema

QGIS 3.18 PostgreSQL 14.

We use `QGIS` to access data from a `PostGIS` server. The data are stored in 33 schemas.

- one contains all the data in 17 tables;
- the others schemas contain views and materialized views created from the first schema as needed.

The "problem" is that it takes several minutes to list all the schemas in the `PostgreSQL` connection window of `QGIS` when we want to connect to the database.
The same behaviour can be seen when using the `export to PostgreSQL (available connections)` plugin : after we choose the database, the list of the schemas takes a very long time to appear.
Is there a way in `PostgreSQL` or `QGIS` to reduce this time or is this normal behaviour ?

Comment: Thirty-three schemas seems quite a few for only 17 core tables. Relational databases are more geared toward accessing rows in tables/views than the catalog, though several minutes seems unusually long. How many objects does QGIS need to sift are sort through?

Comment: Can you provide more informations about the parameters of the PostGIS connexion, it can be faster if the provider doesn't list non-geometric tables for example ?

Comment: There are  2 tables without geometry column. All other tables and views have geometric columns. There are 485 objects (ordinary tables, views and materialized views).Thus, for example, to see the 24 schemas of a specific user, it took  4min 36 sec. Once the schemas are loaded, access to the data is fast.

Comment: It seems that QGIS wants to know at least the geometry type and SRID of each object. I wonder if it means that QGIS must read every row from the views because there may be no fast way for getting that information. Make a try with a schema that has only tables, and where the exact geometry type and SRID of each table is stored into geometry_columns. You can also turn on the SQL statement logging in PostgreSQL and study what SQL queries QGIS sends.

Comment: what do you mean by "**where** the exact geometry type and SRID of each table is stored" ?